# Does $\operatorname{Hom}_A (A / P, M) \not = 0$ imply that $P$ is an associated prime of $M$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> $A$ is Noetherian, $M$ is finitely generated.
>
> Does $\operatorname{Hom}_A (A / P, M) \not = 0$ imply that $P$ is an associated prime of $M$?

I am trying to prove that associated primes respect localization, and I've reduced it to this step (following the hint in Ravi). It follows that there is some $m \in M$ so that $\operatorname{ann}(m) \supseteq P$, but I don't see how to get exact equality.

Comment: @user26857 It is exercise 5.5Nb) in Ravi Vakil's "Foundations of Algebraic Geometry" notes.

Comment: @user26857 I just read the proof of this proposition in Eisenbud's Commutative Algebra. He follows the same beginning as Ravi of proving first that $Hom_A (A/P, M)[U^{-1}] = Hom_{A[U^{-1}]}( A/P[U^{-1}], M[U^{-1}])$, but instead argues that the an injection $\phi : A/P[U^{-1}] \to M[U^{-1}]$ can be decomposed as $\phi = u^{-1} f$, with $f \in Hom_A (A/P, M)$. It follows that $f$ is also injective when $U \cap P = \emptyset$. I guess this is the approach that Ravi's hint was meant to suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\operatorname{Hom}_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Z}/(0),\mathbb{Z}/(2))\neq 0$, but $(0)$ is not an associated prime of $\mathbb{Z}/(2)$.

Comment: Yeah, good point.

Comment: Of course this same argument works for $0 \subset R$ and any $R$ module $M$.